# Can I Reuse A Wordpress Query Twice On Same Page Without Requerying it?

Tags: php, wordpress

Not sure if this is a strange or stupid question, but I have a website with a home page slider that is set up something like the following: (obviously not real class names, but just descriptions of what they are)

```
.... WP QUERY, FEATURED POSTS ...
<ul>UPPER SLIDES CONTAINER</ul>
     <li class="Slide With Background Image">
        <div class="Slide Description">
            <span> Category </span>
            <h2> Title </h2>
        </div>
    </li>
    ....
</ul>

.... SAME WP QUERY, FEATURED POSTS ...
<ul class="Lower Slide Navigation">
    <li class="Slide With Background Image">
        <div class="Slide Description">
            <span> Category </span>
            <h2> Title </h2>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It is set up this way because as the main slides cycle above, the lower slides show previous & next upcoming slides.

Anyways, to my question: is there a way that I can just use one DB query to fill both areas?

It seems inefficient to be making the same call twice...

Comment: cache the information in your first loop, so you can "replay" that cached information for the second section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sure can, all you need to do is 'rewind_posts' after the endif from the first loop and then add your loop again for the slide navigation.

reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts

Comment: I knew it would be something as simple as that, but I just couldn't find it. I love StackOverflow. The people are so helpful in moments when Google searches just keep running me in circles.